# Who to pitch my product for placement in their store?

Tags: communication, process

My team have come up with a product and we are wondering what’s the right person to call to talk about the product being placed in their store.
It’s somewhat a big chain of a tech shop (e.g. Public)

If it’s a special department how is it called and how can I find it?

Thank you.

My apologies if this is the wrong stackexchange to ask my question; I’d appreciate if someone pointed me in the right direction where I can find this info.

Comment: This question is about sales or marketing, rather than the practice or profession of project management as defined in our help center.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/24661/what-is-the-difference-between-business-management-consultant-and-project-manage/24662#24662), the actual *title* of the department/individual is just a name. It doesn't matter.

What does matter is the abilities and desires of the person making the call.

The person needs to be personable, polite, and persuasive. S/he also must *want* to sell the product.

If you still want an actual name, I'd imagine in most places it's the Sales Department that handles this (it is where I've worked).

Comment: Thanks! How would I usually find contact info of the department?

Comment: Ahh, I think I might have not expressed my self correctly. I’m making the call. What I wanted to know is what’s the person in the store that I should be calling about our product, how can I find the right person to call so I can talk about my product being placed in their store?

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov Ooh, I see. In that case, what I would do is just call their customer service and ask them.